# Auto extending lists in windows phone 8 - xaml

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, windows-phone-8, windows-store-apps

What is the terminology for the extended automatic loading of a ListBox in windows phone 8 xaml.

So when you are scrolling and you get to near the bottom of the list, it automatically calls a function or Command or whatever that adds more data to the bottom of the list so you can continue to scroll.

I can't think of what to search for :S

I am using an MVVM style of architecture and have used button Command Bindings for everything, so I guess if there is a Viewmodel way of doing the automatic updating, that'd be swell!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is virtualizing :)

Read about it at the [following](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ptorr/archive/2010/08/16/virtualizing-data-in-windows-phone-7-silverlight-applications.aspx) page, please

Comment: Thanks mate, was confused at what to search for haha.. Was flicking through my unleashed book crying that I couldn't find it haha